# MSBuild, NAnt and Unicode symbols

Tags: unicode, msbuild, nant

%username%.
I have a problem with Unicode symbols while building my custom C++ files with MSBuild and NAnt.
**Overview:**
I write my own extension for MSVS10. In MSBuild scripts I implemented Build, Rebuild and Clean targets. For example in Build target I want to call NAnt.exe with parameters of NAnt build target file and some UNICODE parameter (for example some symbols - ㅇㅀㅇㅀ.cpp). When I call it in MSBuild target with Exec task in Output Window log is OK, I see ㅇㅀㅇㅀ.cpp, but if I use **echo** target in NAnt target I get ????.cpp in log.
I think that this problem in MSBuild, because when I debug my own functions for NAnt written with C# and MSVS10 and in debugging I start NAnt.exe with UNICODE parameters I get normal UNICODE string to my functions.
What do you think about this problem?

Comment: This is confusing.  You seem to be saying that it works when you call from an MSBuild Exec task, but then say it doesn't work when you use echo in NAnt, then say you suspect it is an MSBuild problem.  How can it both work and not work?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NAnt are you using?

NAnt v0.91 now has the ability to specify the encoding to use when calling the  task.
http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/echo.html

```
<echo message="ㅇㅀㅇㅀ.cpp" encoding="unicode" />
```